# iPhone optimized slideUp/slideDown using -webkit-transform

Tags: jquery, iphone, css

I'm trying to create something like the jquery slideUp/slideDown function that uses CSS3 instead of jquery to optimize it for iPhone. I have read that you can use -webkit-transform to make something like it. Maybe I'm wrong and there is a better way?

This is what I've come up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/qE6wa/

The problem is that I want the wrapper-class to start at 0px. Then the wrapper-class and the bounding div should re-size smoothly with the -webkit-transform when the load-btn is clicked. Right now the bounding div just pops to the new height and stays there when you clear. So when you click clear it should resize to the starting size again.
Just like the jquery version.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [2D Transformations](https://github.com/heygrady/transform) plugin? No need to edit anything, just include .js inside the  tag. It will use css transitions in jQuery animation calls when possible.